# Best way to clean an auto-generated SQL schema

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

I am in the final stages implementing an application (Java/Spring) which uses JPA technology for object-relational mapping.

The JPA provider (Hibernate in my case) did a pretty good job auto-generating the DB schema, this is good for ease of use during development.

But, as i am going for production, relying on generated sql is not the best thing, so i need a tool to assist me cleaning and refining the schema.

Any suggestions for tools/ guides/ best practices to use or follow?

BTW, i'll use MySql in production

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want to normalize it, eliminate redundancies and update anomalies, that kind of thing?

Comment: Yes, sure this will help.... also any other tips for producing production grade schema, thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you move to a production environment, you need a schema migration tool such as:

- [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/)
- [FlywayDB](http://flywaydb.org/)

This way you will record every database change into incremental scripts so that you can always recreate a certain application version environment.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip, i know this already, but first i need to clean the existing schema :)

Comment: Those are the tools that can help you migrate your schema incrementally. The *cleaning* part requires manual intervention as you might want to optimize the HBMDDL auto-generated schema anyway.